# TCP buffer doesn't receive more data

Tags: linux, tcp

I have a program which sends some TCP data to the kernel and another application is listening to the port. From my program, I keep sending the data using send() API after polling for space using the poll() API. There are multiple packets to be sent one by one. The TCP data buffer gets filled up after some point and the poll times out. The data is stuck at the buffer and the application which listens does not receive any packets, although the connection is established successfully. 
I have tried to increase the buffer size too, but no luck.
Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Run `strace` on both processes and monitor the sendq in netstat? Nothing will be "stuck at the buffer" unless your consumer isn't really reading. Oh, also, TCP is a _stream_ protocol. Packets are an implementation detail not generally visible at the application level.

Comment: i dont want to see the packets to validate anyway.. Just want to know why the buffer is full and I am unable to send any more data even after polling for 30seconds.

Comment: Look at the process that's supposed to be calling `read` then.

Comment: Listening is not the same thing as reading. Listening just means that you have called `listen()`, which puts the port into LISTENING state. You have to call `read()` or one of the `recv()` family of functions. Clearly you aren't, so the receiver's receive buffer is full, so the sender's send buffer is full, so you can't send.

Comment: The buffer is full because the receiver isn't reading the data? Does the receiver accept the connection and read from the socket?